# How to disable apollo studio to share operations details over it's server?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

In Apollo Server 3.0 or higher version, they come up with apollo studio at place of graphql playground. Apollo Studio provides an option to users to do the login & save the operations (Query & Mutation). By doing so, schema can be shared with others even outside of the organization.

Is there any option available which can disable this login option on apollo studio for security purpose?

Comment: disable "introspection"

Comment: disable introspection is different thing. I'm talking about login option which can be used to share operations over the internet.

Comment: Ah I see! (but idk the answer ;)

Comment: So you want the studio functionality, but not the login?